# The implications of blindly accepting the comments and answers of high rep users

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes

Two days ago I came across this question: [ASP.NET MVC - View not rendering right model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/asp-net-mvc-view-%20%20not-rendering-right-model). It states the problem, the expected result and the actual result, and includes all the code necessary to reproduce the issue. From my understanding this makes it a good question, yet I was amazed to see it had 5 downvotes and no upvotes.

I then started to read the comments, starting with  *"Install fiddler .. your answer is there"*, which I found rather amusing (I don't use fiddler myself but I'm fairly sure it does not debug C# server code). The rest of the comments, while no doubt were well meant, did nothing to help address the issue.

Scrolling down I was more amazed to see a wrong answer had 5 upvotes and no downvotes. Ironically that answer is saying *You cant do this*, then includes a link to the documentation which states you can.

Personally I would have expected that a programmer with a reasonable skillset in C# and/or MVC would have at least taken the time to visually follow the code logic, which in turn would have piqued some interest. Having spent many late nights studying the MVC source code, I spotted the problem, added OP's code to my test project to confirm my thoughts, and then added an answer (since edited to add a bit more explanation of the logic).

I then added a comment questioning the downvotes, and was given a link to this meta question [Is this constructive or am I just being rude?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275689/is-this-constructive-or-am-i-just-being-rude?cb=1). Another users comment questioning why MVC OP was a bad question (since removed) suggested that the questions downvotes and the answers upvotes only started occurring after the meta post. The question has continued to receive more downvotes, although fortunately some recent upvoting has now cancelled most of them out.

My concerns are:

1. A new user has asked their first question, a good one (and yes, it
   does appear to be illogical) but has been downvoted, repeatedly told
   they're wrong, and been abused for it. I'm trying to imagine if I
   would have bothered returning to SO had this happened to me after my
   first question.
2. As a result of the meta post, there appears to have been an
   acceptance that MVC OP is a *"cargo cult programmer"* resulting in
   downvoting the question and upvoting a wrong answer, apparently by users who have not 
   bothered to read or understand the question.
3. *"Good answers are voted up and rise to the top".* Well not always! (for those who haven't got it yet, if the model can't be passed to
   the `Index` method and as is supposedly `null`, why isn't' the first
   line of the `Index` method throwing an exception?)

My question is: Can anything be done to correct this, in particular to reassure MVC OP that this is not (I hope) typical behavior by the SO community?

Comment: I don't do deal with the technologies involved here so my observations only be limited. You answer says "It not clear what your trying to do here." and "But your `if` block makes no sense." Is it possible that some downvoters decided that the unclarity was enough for them to downvote and pass?

Comment: If you hover the mouse on the downvote buttons it says: "This question does not show any research effort; **it is unclear** or not useful". So, given that you mentioned the question as being unclear in your own answer, somebody else may have simply thought of downvoting instead of providing an answer.

Comment: This is "the meta effect". It brings the question to attention of users not active in those tags and technologies who would otherwise never have seen it - or had a view on it.

Comment: @MartinSmith, Indeed, I'm watching it unfold now. I had no idea of the influence of meta. I'll need to spend a bit more time here before forming an opinion as to whether is a good or bad thing (a bit of both I guess)

Comment: @Bakuriu, Both yourself and Louis raise a valid point, but I equate it to seeing a page of code that includes `if(myBool){myBool = true;}`. _"Its unclear why your doing this/its unnecessary/its pointless..."_ but in the end its got nothing to do with why the body of the code is not working, so I think its unlikely that's the reason for the down votes.

Comment: see also [this feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269191/impose-a-24-hour-voting-freeze-on-questions-being-discussed-on-meta) and [this suggested solution](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269201/365237). If we'd get that, I think it would solve a couple of related problems.

Answer (score 3):

What to be done? If you think the question is a good one, vote it up and leave a comment for the asker explaining that SO is a swarm, the units in that swarm don't always agree and that votes apply to the question, not the person who asked the question (to try stop them from taking it personally).

Ditto, if you think the answer is wrong, downvote it. And, if you're feeling magnanimous, leave a comment explaining why.

You have your voting power, use it. The whole swarm nature of the SO collective mind should hopefully end up with the right result eventually.

And if answerer comes back, be prepared to discuss differences of opinion politely. Even if you agree to disagree, you'll be seen to be reasonable.

And *always* remember the voting prime directive: *vote the post, not the poster!*

Comment: vote the post, not the poster ... nor the score