# Second guessing myself - too snarky?

Tags: discussion, questions, comments

In lieu of the coming

> Unwelcoming or snarky” comments classification app

from [Rolling out the welcome wagon](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/06/21/rolling-out-the-welcome-wagon-june-update/?cb=1)

and this users response here:

[How to store data in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003271/how-to-store-data-in-a-list)

.. do I have to unsnark myself?

[image: too snarky?]

Comment: Probably, in most eyes.  There's no dount that it's an appallingly bad 'gimme teh extra codez' question, and I would class it as rude and insulting in itself, but that's a 'dont care' these days, and it's probably better to just downvote and close as 'Too broad or 'Unclear', to avoid identifying yourself and avoid backlash.

Comment: 99% of the time when I dv I provide a reasoning - I hate being dv without (it might be as short as a http://idownvotedbecau.se/ ) but I get your DV/flag/go attitude born from responses like those

Comment: s/reasoning/target  :(

Comment: Worst-case: your comment and username, (and only that - no other context), gets blogged and tattered, (that's like being tarred and feathered, but webscale:), and you become the new 'unwelcoming and hostile' poster-boy on 'iHateSO.com' :  It's now prudent to never comment on downvotes, especially to low-rep OP's.  It's not ideal, but it's much safer for you:(

Comment: just end every comment with ;) and you're good ... ;)

Comment: The question actually worse than it looks at first.  Given URI, T&C, Prohibited Conduct: 'Using bots on the Site; data scraping the Site or any part of the Site'.  The OP is requesting SO help with breaching the T&C of a site.  Anyone who helps with such endeavours should consult a lawyer first to make sure that they cannot be partially liable.

Comment: It's all down to perception, again:(  The people who read the 'hate SO' blogs and totters don't get to understand, or often even see, questions that ask for complete code blocks and functionality to be designed, written, debugged and tested so that they can commit immoral/illegal breaches of ToS and Copyright. All that the computer-illiterati see is 'Oh look! Another SO elitist troll with snarky comments instead of helping' :(

Comment: The existence of "too snarky" implies that there is such thing as "snarky, but not too snarky".

Comment: The first bit of your comment is OK to me but from the start of "I am unable to fly" it's pretty snarky and just rubbing in the same thing you've already said. You could have ended the comment with 'not a problem description' and gotten exactly the same substance across.

Comment: It's a bit snarky, but if you ask me, many posters needs to develop a thicker skin. After all, you were not ONLY mean. You did explain pretty well what the problem was with the question.

Comment: Yes, I think your comment was a bit abrasive, but, on the same token, I don't have sympathy for users who 1) try to use SE as a general 101 and/or 2) don't know how to ask a proper question.

Comment: I believe that kindness is one of the features that can improve the quality of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Do me, do me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51015322/why-is-pycharm-warning-expected-int-got-series-in-series-boolean-operation

Comment: I understand that downvote without comment is bad, I think so too, but some questions are just "obviously bad". (Not this one, however) /// And I agree with most parts of TylerH's comment except the "inability to type" part.

Comment: @JoeMayo "[Quality creates kindness](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366774)".

Comment: @user202729 but at the same time, a lack of quality is not a free pass to be rude.

Comment: Yes, some unsnarking is called for. A good way is to prepare a neutral few text blocks that you can paste togather.

Comment: Interestingly, read in a neutral tone the comment isn't all that snarky. But then, read in a snarky tone it is crazily snarky.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your comment at all. All I'm seeing is a request for clarification, some examples of possible information to provide, and an analogy to clarify your request. Perhaps the implication that they may not have the foresight to understand what you were asking without the analogy may have irked them? But if they don't have the foresight to provide this information upfront, I think it's reasonable to expect that there's a good chance they might find the analogy helpful.

Comment: This politically correct idiocy is the exact reason why I rarely use this site anymore.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Your comment there and the subsequent ones are all pretty snarky. If you want to ask for clarification, ask for clarification. Compare what you wrote to this:

> Can you please explain your problem more thoroughly? Are you getting an error message? Is your data there? How familiar are you with Python lists;  Pandas? What about CSV? Any/all of this information will help us get you a better answer.

Here I've neutrally written what you wrote in the first half of the comment without the condescension. Focus on the information you need, don't get overly clever in what you're saying. Remember there is no way for anyone to read your "tone" in your writing because they can't actually hear you saying it. If you have a [great link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to how to better write a question on SO (which I know exists), do that... include it in your comment.

Heck, link them to the new [question wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369682/ask-a-question-wizard-prototype) that's being developed so that they can see what we really want in a question.

Comment: "Heck" ***FLAGGED***

Comment: Also me: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341410/who-the-heck-is-caroline

Comment: Or if you want to be a bit lazy: "Which part exactly isn't working? (What's the first part that's failing, and what is it doing as opposed to what you expect?)"

Comment: Your suggested comment is better than mine - guess I have to dial down a bit and develop a thicker skin regarding "Gimme" questions. I think I will avoid them in the future.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I really understand the grind of seeing that sort of question over and over again. Every time I get to the point where I'm getting grumpy about it I tell myself to take a step back and let someone else pick up the baton while I focus on something else. SE is working on making the load lighter for users who are really invested and active so that (hopefully) the question quality will improve and it will be less likely to inspire snark. :)

Comment: I hope Catija, that while you step back, you also vote. Vote for the love of god. Nobody can claim you where rude while voting as voting is as impersonal as it gets.

Comment: @Braiam Sure... but I can't vote (or at least downvote) here. :) Part of the main concern for the OP is [not wanting to downvote without explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370014/second-guessing-myself-too-snarky#comment602976_370014), though... whether they choose to change their mind on that is up to them, not my part to dictate.

Comment: yeah, downvoting with explanation is one of those nice things that we can no longer have.  There is nothing, super-nice or super-rude, that can be safely commented instead of serving up an answer. A downvote instead of an answer is now no-...person's-land, and if you stick your head above the parapet by commenting, some sniper will put a bullet in your username.  Keep you head down in the trench.

Comment: FWIW, I would prefer to be on the receiving end of Patrick's comment than this one. Patrick's explains the problem (in an entertaining and philosophical way that might be more likely to make me think about the same sort of considerations when crafting future posts), hints at some possible extra information to provide, and then leaves it to my judgement how to resolve it. This one demands four specific pieces for information, yet even if I provided all of them it might still not result in an answerable question. As such, I think Patrick's approach is both more useful and more respectful.

Answer (score 4):

I've answered [a question in the past](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275689/is-this-constructive-or-am-i-just-being-rude/275714) that this immediately made me think of - I'm not sure it's a duplicate since the scenarios are different, but I'm going to suggest the same answer I did there:

A good rule of thumb is that if after looking at your comment yourself, you feel like you ought to get outside advice on whether you're being rude, that's probably a good sign that you ought to dial things back.

Answer (score -1):

Your comment was fine.

The OP needs to understand that if they want free help then they need to make it easy (or, at least, *possible*) for said help to be provided. Your message gave perhaps humourous examples but nothing about it was rude or condescending.

On the other hand, the response you received *was* extremely rude and showed that the OP's first reaction to being prompted to actually do some thinking/work is to lash out with personal attacks.

The appropriate counter-response then is, of course, walking away and leaving them to solve it themselves. Life's too short.

*Disclaimer: This suggestion follows the "actual life common sense" approach rather than the official "be more welcoming through active subservience" approach.*

Comment: *"be more welcoming through active subservience"* -- that's good stuff right there. Unfortunately, it goes against the "Be Nice or else" policy. Now, on a completely unrelated subject, what size shoes do you wear?